# Defining the Fourier projection operator on $H^{-1}$ so that it moves freely on the dual pairing?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

Let us consider the circle $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and for any $g \in L^2(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$, define $P_N : L^2(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C}) \to L^2(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$ as
\begin{equation}
[P_Ng](x)=\sum_{k=-N}^N \langle g, e_k\rangle_{L^2} e_k(x) 
\end{equation}
where $e_k(x):=e^{2\pi ikx}$. That is, $P_N$ is the Fourier projection operator.

Now, consider the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$ and its dual $H^{-1}(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$, with the dual pairing $\langle , \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^{1}}$

Then, I wonder how I can make sense of $P_N$ as a projection on $H^{-1}(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$ so that
\begin{equation}
\langle P_N f,   \phi \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^{1}}=\langle  f,  P_N \phi \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^{1}}
\end{equation}
for $f \in H^{-1}$ and $\phi \in H^{1}$.

Could anyone please explain for me?

Comment: Why not read the right hand side of that equation as the definition of the left hand side?

Comment: @RhysSteele   Didn't you mean the opposite? That is, the left-hand side is the definition of the right-hand side?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, It's a bit more usual to write the dual pairing with the functional first and the vector second so I didn't read carefully and assumed the $H^{-1}$ slot came first

Comment: This is a common pattern for distributions. For example, translation is first defined for points then 'dualised' to functions and then 'dualised' again to distributions. The fourier transform and convolution are first defined for functions and then 'dualised' to distributions and so on

Comment: @RhysSteele I changed the order of dual pairing in accordance with common usage.